# Highstock set rangeselector data according to displayed data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

There is an issue with the rangeselector. When I have multiple dataseries in one chart and press on the labels at the bottom the rangeselector chart stays all the same.

`legend:{
       enabled:true
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/cL9u2c7v/

Imagine you have one dataseries going to January 2016 and one dataseries going to March 2016. Then you will have empty space if the rangeselector shows only the dataseries of January 2016.

Is there anyone who had the same issue and knwos how to fix it?

Comment: I assume you mean the navigator with the graph in it of a given series? It defaults to series 0, but you can change it, see the API: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But how do I know which series is displayed currently? The User can show and hide the series dynamically.

Comment: Since the navigator can only show one series, how would you handle one series from January to July, and another series from June to December? Then there's no "correct series", since they both have unique timespans.

Comment: It defaults to series 0, i.e. the first one. In this case MSFT. You might be able to change it dynamically but I'm not sure.

Comment: You could define another series that will have data made out of merged series data and use it as navigator series - API: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series That series can be later [updated like any other series](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.update) - update or [setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.setData) can be triggered e.g. in [legendItemClick event](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series<line>.events.legendItemClick)